# How does the test in Devs prove the multiverse theory?

Tags: tv, devs

In *[Devs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devs)*, there is a scene where IIUC Lyndon is given a test to prove the multiverse or many worlds theory. How does the test prove the existence of the multiverse?

Answerers: please use the hide spoilers feature if you go into detail.

Comment: How come the title says string theory but the body says multiverse theory? They aren't the same thing, are they? Or are they? (I'm not a scientist.)

Comment: Devs is a science fiction tv show and from what I know the multiverse is related to string theory. Changed the title to say multiverse.

Comment: The multiverse is part of string theory (essentially it's the space of possible solutions of the theory). I've only seen the first 4 episodes of Devs, but I remember they are concerned with *many worlds* which is an interpretation of quantum mechanics. Did the test concern "many worlds" or the "multiverse"? (Of course, the terms are often confused, and maybe the show's writes didn't use the correct phrase).

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez However I believe the term "multiverse", as a piece of science-fictional gobbledegook, may be older than string theory.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Devs/comments/ftujp0/what_are_the_implications_of_the_conversation/

Comment: @user1411 Oh definitely, it's a very old term. It does have a specialized meaning in the context of string theory, and that meaning is not relevant here. To make the question clearer I'd be tempted to replace all the "multiverse" references to "many-worlds".

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez interesting. the question should use the wording they use in the show

Comment: @1.21gigawatts Did they say "multiverse" in the show? That's a pity, "many worlds" would have been much more precise (and sounds just as sciencey).

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez indeed :) I'll check when I'm able to

Comment: it doesn't 'prove' anything. At best if what she is saying is correct, in 1 out of a million times, he won't fall and gets to come back to DEVS. But - ultimately, he's simply manipulated into (almost certainly) being * pushed * off the bridge.

Comment: @NKCampbell put your comment into an answer and add spoiler tags

Comment: @user14111 No they are not. "Multiverse" is the emergency exit of shame to make "String Theory" somehow relevant to the Real World (as opposed to relevant to Mathematics) and keep the funding coming to the HEP physics department. Nobody knows what it is anyway, More on Peter Woit's blog.

Answer (score 2):

Which test is that? Two scenes spring to mind.

There is one in which Lyndon teeters on the edge of a dam. There is a 50-50 chance of him falling off and dying and I *think* the theory is that in a multiverse his/her consciousness would switch to the alternate reality in which he/she survives. It's related in a way that I don't understand to the [Strong Anthropic Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthropic_principle) which can be used to crack strong encryption... link a random number generator to a doomsday weapon in a way that the doomsday weapon explodes if the RNG doesn't guess the correct key.

There is also a scene in which Lyndon uses the multiverse-theory to improve the audio-retrieval of a scene in the past by gathering information across alternate pasts. Forest sacks him on the spot because Forest wants to recreate his personal past digitally as a virtual world, not an amalgam of possible pasts.

Comment: It's the bridge scene I'm referring to.

Comment: I am not aware of a plausible theory suggesting that the anthropic principle (if true) could be used as a means of decoding encryption. In your hypothetical situation, there would be a set of universes that tried such a method. In the vast majority, the weapon would kill everyone; in a very small subset, the code would be cracked. That small subset is statistically equivalent in size to the set of universes where the code is cracked without any weapon. There has been no improvement in the efficacy of the decryption method.

Comment: It's easy enough to see that there is no "switching", only the cessation of existence of a given consciousness in most of the universes of the set. The principle that would let you conclude something else would be the so-called final anthropic principle, which asserts that intelligent life cannot cease to exist. This is a purely philosophical guess, in my opinion, with little empirical or logical backing.